# scraping all tables from a single webpage?

Tags: r, xml, rselenium

For the first site the data is scraped into the `reservoirs` `data.frame` that just needs some tidying, but for the second there's two sets of tables, an upper and lower, and I don't know how to get the lower.

sites:

1) http://cdec.water.ca.gov/reportapp/javareports?name=RES

2) http://cdec.water.ca.gov/reportapp/javareports?name=FNF

```
library(tidyverse)
library(XML)

reservoirs <-  "http://cdec.water.ca.gov/reportapp/javareports?name=RES" %>% 
               readHTMLTable() %>% 
               data.frame()  

flows_part1 <- "http://cdec.water.ca.gov/reportapp/javareports?name=FNF" %>% 
               readHTMLTable() %>% 
               data.frame()


#flows_part2 <- ??
```

Any ideas on how to get the second table from the second site (or a better way to get everything initially?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The readHTMLTable function will store all of the tables into a list which can then be extracted from each list element.

```
flows <-  readHTMLTable("http://cdec.water.ca.gov/reportapp/javareports?name=FNF", as.data.frame = TRUE)

flows_part1 <- flows[[1]]
flows_part2 <- flows[[2]]
```